# Uri throws invalid port for WPF style uri

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

I am trying to initialize a BitmapImage instance in code with wpf style uri.

```
BitmapImage icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAssembly;component/Icons/someIcon.ico", UriKind.Absolute));
```

But the problem is `new Uri` throws `System.UriFormatException`

> Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

what have I done wrong?

Comment: Are you actually doing this while running a WPF application? You will get this message if the 'pack' scheme is not registered, and it's registered as soon as a `System.Windows.Application` is created.

Comment: @CharlesMager running on a Winform hosted WPF application. Guess that's why

Comment: Try adding `new System.Windows.Application();` in your `Program.Main` method (where your initialise the WinForms app).

Comment: @CharlesMager works like a charm. Type out an answer and I will be more than happy to accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that you're attempting to create the `Uri` in an application that isn't a normal WPF application.  `Uri` has a number of built in 'schemes' that are registered with the [`UriParser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The UriParser class enables you to create parsers for new URI schemes. You can write these parsers in their entirety, or the parsers can be derived from well-known schemes (HTTP, FTP, and other schemes based on network protocols).

WPF adds a parser for the 'pack' scheme when a `System.Windows.Application` is created, which is the normal entry point for a WPF application.  In your case you can just add a call to this in your composition root:

```
new System.Windows.Application();
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the following code

```
UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
```

before trying to create the uri.